# How to put a String of ints into an array of ints?

Tags: java, compilation, compiler-errors

Sandboxx:

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import static java.lang.System.*;
    import static java.util.Arrays.*;

 public class Sandboxx
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
   {



     Construct ion = new Construct(3, "3, 2, 1, 0");

   }

}
```

Construct:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;
import static java.util.Arrays.*;

public class Construct
{

  int length;
  String s;


  public Construct() {

  }

  public Construct(int _length) {

  }

   public Construct(String _s) {

  }

  public Construct(int _length, String _s) {

     length = _length;
    s = _s;

    Scanner chopper = new Scanner(s);

    int[] nums = new int[3];
    while (chopper.hasNextInt()) {

       nums = chopper.nextInt();
    }

  }

}
```

I am trying to put a string of ints, (s) into an array of ints (nums). I wrote this code, but I get this error: Error: /Users/bobgalt/Construct.java:41: '.class' expected. I am a novice at java as you can see, but I can't seem to figure out how to put the String of ints into an array of ints. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your question is "How do I parse the string "3, 2, 1, 0" into a set of integers?"

The easiest answer is String.split().

EXAMPLE (*untested*):

```
  String s = "3, 2, 1, 0";
  String a[] = s.split(",");
  int[] nums = new int[a.length];
  for (int i=0; i < a.length; i++)
     nums[i] = Integer.parseInt(a[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:-

```
String s= "{3,2,1,0}";
String[] x= s.replaceAll("\\{", "").replaceAll("\\}", "").split(",");

int[] s= new int[x.length];

for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    try {
        s[i] = Integer.parseInt(x[i]);
    } catch (Exception e) {};
}
```